# InfoPath Forms move to another environment

Tags: development, infopath, deployment

I have a question regarding the InfoPath Forms 2010.

I've created in my DEV environment Templates which I would like to use for ListA, I've created them and tested on my environment all is good.

Now I want to make it ready to move to another environment like test and later to production. How can I do that?
What is the best solution?

Even if I open the template in publishing window I only see the URL to ListA in dev environment and I cannot change it.

The best solution would be to use powershell but how to make sure everything will be ok?

Comment: Have you modfied the list form or created admin approved Infopath form? I mainly worked with the second option and you can change the publishing target. Have you tried to save list as template and upload it to test?

Comment: Yes, the template is there, BUT I cannot republish it, as it says the list doesn't exist and for another example which have a lookup it cannot find it anymore so it does not work. It is hard coupled to list id and list id's are different